# E se eu não quiser nenhum queryset numa view do Django?

Tags: python, django

Existem urls que preciso apenas setar uma session ou consultar uma API restful....enfim. E se eu não quero um queryset? Pq o django parece me obrigar a definir um?

Teria algum tipo de view diferente para isso?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja usando generic view (por isso sua impressão de necessitar de uma query), veja todos os tipos de generic views:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/

Generic view mais básica:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View

class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

Caso precise renderizar template:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from articles.models import Article

class HomePageView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['latest_articles'] = Article.objects.all()[:5]
        return context
```